# Google Apps Script - if else statement for loop to allocate the value

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, google-apps-script

I am new to GAS.
Need to write a script to execute the following calculation:

There are currently 87 employees who should be distributed for the week with a limit of 18 employees per day.
I have percentage allocation (col B). These percentages are based on other calculations and will change month over month.

What  the team lead is currently doing - simple calculation in spreadsheet (multiplying % by 87). And then he manually adjusts numbers to have max of 18 per day (last column - is what needs to be at the end)

```
        allocation  number   recount

Mon     0.21        18       18
Tue     0.08        7        7
Wed     0.22        19       18
Thu     0.12        10       11
Fri     0.25        22       18
Sat     0.07        6        10
Sun     0.05        4        4
```

Issues:

1. Total number of allocated staff after rounding is 86 (e.g. because 87*0.21 = 18.27 --> 18 employees)
2. If on some day it turns to be more than 18 employees (e.g. on Wed it is 22%*87=19 employees), only 18 people can be assigned to this day and remaining should be moved to the next "busiest" day (meaning day with the highest %). This is Friday, but on Friday we already have 22, so one from Wednesday should go to Thursday. And 4 extra from Friday go to Saturday.

Sounds complicated. But that's what I need - to automate adjustments, in other words to get column Recount from the column Number

I started the code, but have no idea how to proceed

Would be very grateful for any tips

```
function allocate() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var staff=ss.getSheetByName('staff');
  var max = ss.getRange('B1').getValue();

  for (var r=4; r<=10; r++)
  {
    var days=staff.getRange(r,2).getValue();
    staff.getRange(r,3).setValue(days*max);
  }
}

function round()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var staff=ss.getSheetByName('staff');
  for (var r=4; r<=10; r++)
  {
    var num=staff.getRange(r,3).getValue();
    staff.getRange(r,3).setValue(Math.round(num));
  }
}
```

Comment: I cannot understand about your logic. 1. Can you modify "allocation" values? Because when "allocation" values are 0.21 and 0.22, those are ``87 * 0.21 = 18.27`` and ``87 * 0.22 = 19.14``, respectively. At this time, the results are over 18 of the limitation you are saying. 2. About ``I wrote this code to have not more than 18 per day``, there is a value of ``87 * 0.25 = 21.75``. This has already been over 18. How about this? 3. If you think that you are required to add more information for correctly understanding your logic, please update your question. It will help users think of your issue.

Comment: @Tanaike  thanks, I have edited the question. 
We allocate 87 employees based on % (% comes from another calculation and is not constant variable) and in case we receive >18 per day, extra people should be reallocated to another day. This is done manually and we want to automate this if possible.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I noticed that an answer has already been posted now. I think that it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to treat it on a week basis, not per day. Probably it is simplest to think of the task as removing marbles from a bag, until either your allocation quota is met, or the maximum draws are made. Then, advance to the next day.

E.g. (untested)

```
function allocate() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("weekly roster");
  const numStaff = 50; // sheet.getRange("whatever cell you store this in").getValue();
  const percentages = sheet.getRange("B4:B10").getValues();
  const allotmentRange = sheet.getRange("C4:C10");
  const maxPerDay = 5;

  const allocated = [
    [0],
    [0],
    [0],
    [0],
    [0],
    [0],
    [0]
  ];
  var remaining = numStaff;
  var day = 0;
  while (remaining > 0 && day < allocated.length) {
    if (allocated[day][0] < maxPerDay && allocated[day][0] / numStaff < percentages[day][0]) {
      --remaining;
      ++allocated[day][0];
    } else {
      ++day;
    }
  }
  /* Add code to go back through allocated and add any remaining unused staff if the number is less than maxPerDay (i.e. ignoring percentage this time) */

  // Write the worker allotment for the week.
  allotmentRange.setValues(allocated);
}
```